# How to visualize standard deviation in a one-dimensional plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, standard-deviation

I plot the values of one variable as points on a one dimensional line (in an otherwise empty two-dimensional space). I would like to illustrate **variation around the mean** (i.e. standard deviation) in that graph. The SD is about 2. Thus I am thinking about a two-sided arrow of that size centered at the mean. How can I do this in `ggplot2`? (The arrows in the example are plain paint and may be different in ggplot.)

```
library(tidyverse)

data(sleep)

ggplot(aes(x=extra, y=c(0)), data=sleep) + 
  geom_point(size=3) +
  labs(title="Distribution of a variable around the mean") +
  geom_vline(xintercept=mean(sleep$extra), size=1.5, color="red") 

sd(sleep$extra)
2.01792
```

[image]

Edit: I found this source http://stla.overblog.com/schematizing-the-variance-as-a-moment-of-inertia using an elipse with arrow which I also find very compelling.

Comment: If you want to visualise the distribution of a univariate variable, the typical way is to display it as a histogram or kernel density estimate, possibly with a rug plot.

Comment: I know, but I start from one dimension, later add a second dimension and extend the idea from variance to covariance. Thus I need this particular setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your direct question on showing standard deviation, it might be simplest to use the errorbar (vertical error bars) or errorbarh (horizontal error bars) geom.  Here's how to show that in your example:

```
ggplot(aes(x=extra, y=c(0)), data=sleep) + 
  geom_errorbarh(xmin=mean(sleep$extra) - sd(sleep$extra), xmax=mean(sleep$extra) + sd(sleep$extra)) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  labs(title="Distribution of a variable around the mean") +
  geom_vline(xintercept=mean(sleep$extra), size=1.5, color="red")
```

[image]

Customarily, it's more common to visualize the distribution in one dimension via a boxplot.  Here's an example of how you might apply that here:

```
ggplot(aes(x=extra, y=c(0)), data=sleep) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  labs(title="Distribution of a variable around the mean") +
  geom_vline(xintercept=mean(sleep$extra), size=1.5, color="red")
```

[image]

You'll notice the stat used for boxplot is customarily different.  It's showing you median and quantiles, rather than mean and standard deviation.

Comment: Is there a way to horizontally shift the `geom_vline`?

Comment: Horizontal shifting of `geom_errorbarh` is done via `xmin` and `xmax`.  There's no point designated as the center of that... so not quire sure what you mean.  The bar is draw as a line connecting the `xmin` and `xmax`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use something like `geom_errorbar` from the `ggplot2` package

```
df <- data.frame(means = rnorm(20, 5, 2),
                   sds = rnorm(20),
                 feats = c(paste0("Feature ", letters[1:10])),
                 group = rep(c("group 1", "group 2"), each = 2))


library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = feats, color = group)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = means + sds, ymin = means - sds),
                position = "dodge")
```